ROS "image_view" not displaying published image pop up window
Does anyone know why the published image to my /projector/image topic is not showing up after running my node and rosrun image_view image_view image:=/projector/image? I have attached my code below. Thanks!
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("/projector/image", 1);

    std::string image_path = "/home/fetch/catkin_ws/src/search_rescue_evaluation/image/black_screen_image.jpg";
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    if (!image.empty()) {
        sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", image).toImageMsg();
        
        pub.publish(msg);
        ROS_INFO("Image published to '/projector/image' topic.");
    } else {
        ROS_ERROR("Failed to load the image from: %s", image_path.c_str());
    }

    ros::spin(); 

    return 0;
}


Hi! Have you verified that the images are actually being published, e.g. with rostopic echo /projector/image?

Hi Luca!
The image is not published unless I do it multiple times. Using a loop helped rather than publishing one. I think image_view was developed to stream images from a camera, which might be why it is not displaying just an image.
Thank you!

Glad it helped! Were you launching your node and image_view at the same time from a launch file? It could be just a matter of timing... Maybe your node published the single image before image_view is up and running (or you have the time to issue the rostopic echo command).
